# How to get real path from Android dropbox URI?

Tags: android

Below URI i am getting from selecting file from dropbox.

```
content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/f9326bb2-272c-47dd-94da-37e66360c48f
```

Below is code i am using to select document

```
documentIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        documentIntent.setType("application/*");
        ((AddProjectActivity) context).startActivityFromFragment(this, documentIntent, PICK_DOCUMENT);
```

How to get real path from above URI?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Comment: @subrahmanyam - Did you find any solutions to this ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: No I did not find solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get real path from above URI

Content provider's URI does not need to be resolvable to any existing file. There's no requirement for that so while you may save what CP served to file if you need to, Content Provider may serve it as it likes i.e. by generating the content, fetching-from-net-while-serving, anything else. Also, in case there's file (i.e. cache) it may not be accessible to your process.

Further read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Yes. I am not able access that file. FileNotFound(Permission denied) error getting(This is happening in nexus 6P, tried in samsung devices working fine).

Comment: You should read docs I linked as it looks you not really getting the concept of CP. Again there may nit be any file. Read stream  from CP

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for quite some time now. I found out that it occurred with Android 7 (API 25). With API 23 my code for opening a file from dropbox (for example) with the Intent selector works fine. There is no filecache involved. With Android 7 it is just broken. My failing test with API 25 is on a AVD Nexsu. May successful test with API 23 is on a Samsung J5. So it may also be a problem with devices other than Samsung as stated above in the comment.